# Max-height to kendo grid rows with a texteditor

Tags: html, jquery, css, frontend, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid where I want to set a max row height but I have fields where you can click into the grid item and use an editor to put some comments, make them bold, etc... I want that same functionality but want the user to only see the first X amount of characters so the page space is not taken up by a wall of text. I've tried following the advice from this post [Max-Height to kendo grid cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425859/max-height-to-kendo-grid-cells?newreg=13d77088fcb4486b96657a7632d2ac61) and other things I've found online, but no luck so far. Any advice appreciated! Specifically not looking for a grid row height, but a row height max.

Putting a max height on the grid row, and following that last post. Tried messing around with the HTML on the page itself but nothing seems to do it.

Comment: hi, can you show us your code?